# Converting byte array (char array) to an integer type (short, int, long)

Tags: c++

I was wondering if system endianness matters when converting a byte array to a short / int / long. Would this be incorrect to do if the code runs on both big-endian and little-endian machines?

```
short s = (b[0] << 8) | (b[1]);
int i = (b[0] << 24) | (b[1] << 16) | (b[2] << 8) | (b[3])
```

Comment: If you are doing it on the same machine then no it doesn't matter, if you are sending it over the network to a machine that *might* have a different endian-ness and then trying to convert, then yes it does matter.

Comment: Short answer is that endianness matters for integers larger than 1 byte.  Not for anything else (on 'normal' computers)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, endianness matters. In little endian you have the most significant byte in the upper part of the short or int - i.e. bits 8-15 for short and 24-31 for int. For big endian the byte order would need to be reversed:

```
short s = ((b[1] << 8) | b[0]);
int i = (b[3] << 24) | (b[2] << 16) | (b[1] << 8) | (b[0]);
```

Note that this assumes that the byte array is in little endian order. Endianness and conversion between byte array and integer types depends not only on the endianness of the CPU but also on the endianness of the byte array data.

It is recommended to wrap these conversions in functions that will know (either via compilation flags or at run time) the endianness of the system and perform the conversion correctly.

In addition, creating a standard for the byte array data (always big endian, for example) and then using the `socket` `ntoh_s` and `ntoh_l` will offload the decision regarding endianness to the OS `socket` implementation that is aware of such things. Note that the default network order is big endian (the `n` in `ntoh_x`), so having the byte array data as big endian would be the most straight forward way to do this.

As pointed out by the OP (@Mike), `boost` also provides endianness conversion functions.

Comment: How would you have byte array data with a different endianness than the CPU on the same machine ?

Comment: Hmm okay, having all the byte arrays in big-endian does make things easier. So for converting to the actual types I can just use something like boost's asio library to do the conversions after the above code (eg s = ntohs(s)), and when encoding I can use htons()

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - Easy: for the short 0x1234 you can have the byte arrays [0x12, 0x34] and [0x34, 0x12]. The first is in big endian, and the second is in little endian.

Comment: No, you have two byte arrays in the *same* endianness with different values.

Comment: @Mike - I'm not familiar with `boost`, but yes, using functions that perform the conversion is the best option.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - or two byte arrays with different endianness and the same value. It's semantics, but something that is important to understand when working with data across endianness.

Comment: @EliIser The point I am trying to make is that if you are on the same machine, there is no such thing as *across* endianness. The way things are stored on disk is determined by the endianness of the machine architecture.

Comment: @EliIser Boost just makes it so htonl and such functions are portable (and don't rely soley on windows API). Thanks

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - since the OP refers to code that will run on different machines, there is cross-endianness concerns. Since we can't know where the byte array originated from, I believe my answer gives the more generic way to handle endianness. If the byte array was generated on the same machine directly from a variable, you'd be correct. But converting to byte array and back again is just silly.

Answer (score 4):

```
// on little endian:

unsigned char c[] = { 1, 0 };       // "one" in little endian order { LSB, MSB }

int a = (c[1] << 8) | c[0];         // a = 1
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
// on big endian:

unsigned char c[] = { 0, 1 };       // "one" in big endian order { MSB, LSB }

int a = (c[0] << 8) | c[1];         // a = 1
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
// on little endian:

unsigned char c[] = { 0, 1 };       // "one" in big endian order { MSB, LSB }

int a = (c[0] << 8) | c[1];         // a = 1 (reverse byte order)
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
// on big endian:

unsigned char c[] = { 1, 0 };       // "one" in little endian order { LSB, MSB }

int a = (c[1] << 8) | c[0];         // a = 1 (reverse byte order)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use unions for this. Endianness matters, to change it you can use x86 BSWAP instruction (or analogues for another platforms), provided by the most of c compilers as an intrinsic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef union{
  unsigned char bytes[8];
  unsigned short int words[4];
  unsigned int dwords[2];
  unsigned long long int qword;
} test;
int main(){
  printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", sizeof(char), sizeof(short), sizeof(int), sizeof(long), sizeof(long long));
  test t;
  t.qword=0x0001020304050607u;
  printf("%02hhX|%02hhX|%02hhX|%02hhX|%02hhX|%02hhX|%02hhX|%02hhX\n",t.bytes[0],t.bytes[1] ,t.bytes[2],t.bytes[3],t.bytes[4],t.bytes[5],t.bytes[6],t.bytes[7]);
  printf("%04hX|%04hX|%04hX|%04hX\n" ,t.words[0] ,t.words[1] ,t.words[2] ,t.words[3]);
  printf("%08lX|%08lX\n" ,t.dwords[0] ,t.dwords[1]);
  printf("%016qX\n" ,t.qword);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's fine as far as endianness is concerned, but you may have problems if your `int`s are only 16 bits wide.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as you've specified, where you are using an existing byte array, will work fine across all machines.  You will end up with the same answer.

However, depending on how you are creating that stream, it may be affected by endianness and you may not end up with the number you think you will.