# Conversion of big-endian long in C++?

Tags: c++, bit-shift, endianness, integer-promotion

I need a C++ function that returns the value of four consecutive bytes interpreted as a bigendian long. A pointer to the first byte should be updated to point after the last. I have tried the following code:

```
inline int32_t bigendianlong(unsigned char * &p)  
{  
  return (((int32_t)*p++ << 8 | *p++) << 8 | *p++) << 8 | *p++;  
}
```

For instance, if p points to 00 00 00 A0 I would expect the result to be 160, but it is 0. How come?

Comment: What about [ntohl()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ntohl.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting byte array (char array) to an integer type (short, int, long)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678166/converting-byte-array-char-array-to-an-integer-type-short-int-long)

Comment: You have multiple modifications of `p` that are not sequenced relative to each other. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: Use p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3] and increment p separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is explained clearly by this warning (emitted by the compiler):

```
./endian.cpp:23:25: warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'p' [-Wunsequenced]
    return (((int32_t)*p++ << 8 | *p++) << 8 | *p++) << 8 | *p++;
```

Breaking down the logic in the function in order to explicitly specify sequence points...

```
inline int32_t bigendianlong(unsigned char * &p)
{
    int32_t result = *p++;
    result = (result << 8) + *p++;
    result = (result << 8) + *p++;
    result = (result << 8) + *p++;
    return result;
}
```

... will solve it

Comment: Thank you. I thought the parentheses would account for unambiguous sequencing. My compiler gives no warning.

Comment: The parentheses ensure he order of arithmetic, not the side-effects of ++. The standard's wording explicitly allows the implementation to apply the post-increment at any time after the use of p and before the next sequence point (comma or semicolon). Shame you got no warning. Perhaps turn up your warning levels?

Answer (score 0):

This function is named `ntohl()` (convert Network TO Host byte order Long) on both Unix and Windows, or `g_ntohl()` in glib.  Add 4 to your pointer afterward.  If you want to roll your own, a union type whose members are a `uint32_t` and a `uint8_t[4]` will be useful.