# How to convert a char array of hex values to a single integer value in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, hex

I have a char array of hex values and would like to convert them into a single integer value. I have two issues with the code I am currently using:

**Problem 1:** the value stored in strHex after running this is - "0927ffffffc0" when I want it to be "000927C0" - what is the reason for the extra "ffffff" being added?

**Problem 2:** I would like a solution to convert a char array of hex values to an integer without using stringstream if possible.

```
char cArray[4] = { 0x00, 0x09, 0x27, 0xC0 }; // (600000 in decimal)

std::stringstream ss;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    ss << std::hex << (int)cArray[i];
}
std::string strHex = ss.str();

int nHexNumber;
sscanf(strHex.c_str(), "%x", &nHexNumber);
```

nHexNumber should be 600000 when converted and its giving me -64.

Comment: Please only tag the language being used.

Comment: The "hex values" for the initialisation are irrelavant - each element is `char` but `unsigned char` would be better.

Comment: Use `unsigned char` instead of `char`

Comment: @drescherjm IMO it is better to not write code that depends on system endianness

Comment: Why do you say that _{0, 9, 39, 192}_ is "600,000" in decimal?

Comment: 927C0 converted from hex to decimal is 600000

Comment: So - what you really want is to *concatenate* hex *strings* and convert the resulting string to decimal, right?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Comment: you are sign-extending the values when casting to `int`.  0xC0 is `10100000` in binary.  Apparently `char` is considered to be a signed type, so when extending it to fit your 4-byte `int` type, it prepends a bunch of `1`s to it to preserve the value rather than turn a negative number into a positive number by zero-extending.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons - Thanks, fixed that by changing to unsigned char - still interested in a solution that does not involve stringstream though.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678166/converting-byte-array-char-array-to-an-integer-type-short-int-long) then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        unsigned char cArray[4] = { 0x00, 0x09, 0x27, 0xC0 };
        uint32_t nHexNumber = (cArray[0] << 24) | (cArray[1] << 16) | (cArray[2] << 8) | (cArray[3]);

        std::cout << std::hex << nHexNumber << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

**Edited:** As pointed out by [M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m) this is not depending on [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) as originally stated.

Output under QEMU:

```
user@debian-powerpc:~$ uname -a
Linux debian-powerpc 3.2.0-4-powerpc #1 Debian 3.2.51-1 ppc GNU/Linux
user@debian-powerpc:~$ ./a.out
927c0
user@debian-powerpc:~$
```

Under Ubuntu on Windows:

```
leus@owl:~$ uname -a
Linux owl 4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
leus@owl:~$ ./a.out
927c0
leus@owl:~$
```

Comment: This solution is NOT dependent on endianness.  But it would be undefined behaviour if `int` is 16-bit, or if the high bit of `cArray[0]` is `1`.

Comment: You have a good point about the first byte being 1, or `int` being 16 bits (or 64, for that matter). But why do you say this is endian-safe?

Comment: It will produce the same result regardless of the system endianness

Comment: Am I not putting the first byte in the fourth position, then the second in the third, the third in the second and the last byte in the first? How is that the resulting four bytes aren't ordered with the most significant byte last?

Comment: You're creating the value `600000` (in decimal) regardless of the representation. The code would have the same output on any endianness of 32-bit+ system

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

union {
    unsigned char cA[4] = { 0x00, 0x09, 0x27, 0xc0 };
    int k;
} u;

int main() 
{
    cout << htonl(u.k) << endl;
}
```

simple way is to use htonl...

Comment: In C++ it's undefined behaviour to read a union member that was not the last one written. Also `htonl` is not part of Standard C++

Comment: Then can you change this code to a complete code? It's better to give a productive advice than just to say it won't work..

Comment: The other posted answer is close to being complete

Comment: Maybe you should read your own link? It supports what I said in my first comment.  "The lifetime of a union member begins when the member is made active. If another member was active previously, its lifetime ends." `cA` is active by virtue of being initialized, `k` is inactive and therefore you read a variable outside of its lifetime.  Also see the very first line of the page, "A union is a special class type that can hold only one of its non-static data members at a time."

Comment: This is a basiic union usage.. In fact I don't know any compiler that will generate undefined behavior. Can you name one?

Comment: undefined behaviour is specified by the C++ Standard, not by compilers . Working as expected is one possible manifestation of undefined behaviour, so you could say that all compilers exhibit UB

Comment: You are going to write a thesis about this.. Just see the idea of my code. Let's wrap this.

Comment: The issue here is that `union` is a different beast in C++ than what it was in C. In C it did work as expected; in C++ the behaviour is indeed undefined, although most compilers do the sane thing (type punning). [More details in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning).