Int32's from byte stream
I have a byte stream like
uint8_t buf[] = { 0xFF, 0x1B, … , 0x34 }; // approx. 800 Bytes

Now, I want to extract various ints from known positions and store them in their own variables, like "get int64 from index 0x3B of buffer" or "get uint32 from index 0x03".
What's the best way to do?
The stream is big endian, but I could use a byteswap (bswap64()) from ESP32 headers

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678166/converting-byte-array-char-array-to-an-integer-type-short-int-long

There are several ways to convert a number of bytes into a fixed-size integer, one of them is:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static size_t get_integer(uint8_t *buf, size_t start, size_t count)
{
    size_t i, result = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        result |= (size_t)buf[i] << ((count - i - 1) * CHAR_BIT);

    return result;
}


int main()
{
    uint8_t buf[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x32, 0x34, 0x23, 0x65, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00 };

    int r1 = (int)get_integer(buf, 0, sizeof(int));
    long r2 = (long long)get_integer(buf, 8, sizeof(long long));
}

using a function to convert. The other is less safe and consists to cast a pointer and put its value directly into an integer variable:
int r1 = *(int *)(buf + 0);     // where 0 and 12 are the beginning positions
long r2 = *(long *)(buf + 12);


Thanks, I was trying to implement your second suggestion but I did not get the "+ 12" bit. It's works like a charm.

@dexamenos You're welcome, the '+ 12' stands for the position of the first byte of the number in the buffer (the index), thus increasing the pointer to point to the memory cell where the number begins. You then convert the pointer to the type size you need, access its value and get the number you are looking for.

There is no reason to mention the “other” method except to teach students that whenever they see it in code, they should fix it. It violates the aliasing rules in C 2018 6.5 7, and there is no need for it because there are other methods of reinterpreting bytes that are defined by the C standard, notably merely copying the bytes into the desired object type as with memcpy. Further, good compilers recognize such a memcpy and optimize it.

If you have data stored as an uint8_t array(in little Endian) like this:
    uint8_t data[12]= { 0xe8, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe9, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0xea, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00}; // 3 uint32_t value (in little endian) of 1000, 1001, and 1002

All you need is to pointing to the right location and retrieve the data as uint32_t with pointer to the location and deference it.
    uint8_t data[12]= { 0xe8, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe9, 0x03, 0, 0, 0xea, 0x03, 0, 0};
    
    int idx = 1; // get the second uint32_t value which is 1001 (0x000003e9)

    uint32_t data1 = *(uint32_t*) &data[idx * 4];


Besides the flaw that it only works if the stream is in correct byte order, this version might invoke undefined behaviour if the buffer is not just randomly aligned properly for 32 bit accesses.

In addition to the alignment problem, this violates the aliasing requirements in C 2018 6.5 7. The proper way to reinterpret bytes from a buffer such as this would be to copy them into a uint32_t object, as with uint32_t data1; memcpy(&data1, data + offset, sizeof data1);.
